# Efficient algorithm to search for matching substrings longer than 14 characters of a text inside another text

Tags: c++, c, string, algorithm

I've got a long text (about 5 MB filesize) and another text called pattern (around 2000 characters).

The task is to find matching parts from a genom-pattern which are 15 characters or longer in the long text.

example:

long text:
ACGTACGTGTCA
**AAAACCCCGGGGTTTTA**
GTACCCGTAGGCGTAT *AND MUCH LONGER*

pattern:
ACGGTATTGAC
**AAAACCCCGGGGTTTTA**
TGTTCCCAG

I'm looking for an efficient (and easy to understand and implement) algorithm.

A bonus would be a way to implement this with just char-arrays in C++ if thats possible at all.

Comment: Are other characters allowed to intervene?  This is the difference between common subsequences ("ABC" and "ADC" share "AC") and common subwords ("ABC" and "ADC" share only the one-character subwords "A" and "B").

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence_problem

Comment: @JasonZhu This is not exactly the case, he wants all common subsequences longer than 15 chars, not just the longest one.

Comment: @AdamMihalcin Actually its only genom-patterns which consist of the 4 characters A,C,G and T.

Comment: @Hedge: Is space also part of the character set, or do you just use it for formatting the letters to make it easier for us humans? I ask because I am confused about the example. You do not mention treating spaces in any special way, and are talking of _substrings_ instead of for example _words_ or _tokens_. But your example makes them appear significant - you did not mark **AAAACCCCGGGGTTTTA G** as a common substring.

Comment: @FooF: No space is not part of the character set. I also altered the pattern so the common substring is just the bold part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Stand back](http://www.ourspacer.com/images/graphics/political/Stand-the-fuck-back,-I-got-this.jpg), I'm gonna live-code:

```
void match_substring(const char *a, const char *b, int n) // n=15 in your case
{
    int alen = strlen(a); // I'll leave all the null-checking and buffer-overrun business as an exercise to the reader
    int blen = strlen(b);
    for (int i=0; i<alen; i++) {
        for (int j=0; j<blen; j++) {
            for (int k; (i+k<alen) && (j+k<blen) && a[i+k]==b[i+k]; k++);
            if (k >= n)
                printf("match from (%d:%d) for %d bytes\n", i, j, k);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: that one is called Naïve string search, I went with it. An easy to implement improvement would be the Knuth–Morris–Pratt algorithm.

Answer (score 7):

Here's one algorithm - I'm not sure if it has a name.  It requires a "rolling hash" - a (non-cryptographic) hash function that has the property that given the hash of a sequence `AB...C`, it is efficient to calculate the hash of the sequence `B...CD`.

1. Calculate the rolling hashes of the sequences `pattern[0..14]`, `pattern[1..15]`, `pattern[2..16]`... and store each index in `pattern` in a hash table.
2. Caculate the rolling hash of `haystack[0..14]` and see if it is in the hash table.  If it is, compare `haystack[0..14]` to `pattern[pos..pos+14]` where `pos` was retrieved from the hash table.
3. From the rolling hash of `haystack[0..14]`, efficiently compute the rolling hash of `haystack[1..15]` and see if it is in the hash table.  Repeat until you reach the end of `haystack`.

Note that your 15 character strings only have 2<sup>30</sup> possible values so your "hash function" could be a simple mapping to the value of the string treated as a 15 digit base-4 number, which is fast to compute, has the rolling hash property and is unique.

Comment: I'm not sure, but I suspect this will have tons of collisions in the case of DNA. And even if you're just comparing the hashes, not the full comparison (no collision), it's still the same big-O in time as my algorithm. It does have better cache locality, though.

Comment: @R.: If you size your hash table to get `O(1)` amortised lookups, this should be `O(m+n)` - isn't yours `O(mn)`?

Comment: For each offset in the haystack (`n`), you need to check its hash against not just one but all possible offsets in the pattern (`m`). That is, you compare against `m` different precomputed hashes. That makes the algorithm `O(nm)`.

Comment: @R.: For each offset in the haystack you probe the hash table once.  As long as the hashtable is appropriately sized that should be amortised `O(1)`, not `O(m)`.

Answer (score 4):

One way would be to get hold of an implementation of [Aho-Corasick](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aho%E2%80%93Corasick_string_matching_algorithm) and use it to create something that will recognise any of the 15-character chunks in the pattern, and then use this to search the text. With Aho-Corasick the cost to build the matcher and the cost to search are both linear, so this should be practical.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using a good implementation of the C library (or even a mediocre one like glibc that happens to have a good implementation of this function), `strstr` will do very well. I've heard there's a new algorithm that's especially good for DNA (small alphabet), but I can't find the reference right now. Other than that, 2way (which glibc uses) is optimal.

Comment: Of course it's thread safe. It doesn't modify anything. Or more formally, all functions not specifically documented as non-thread-safe are thread-safe.

Comment: Are you proposing that the OP use `strstr()` on every 15 character subsequence of the 2000-character pattern?

Comment: @caf: I missed that it was **every** 15-character substring of pattern that needs to be searched in the haystack. My answer is still better than brute force, but there's probably a better algorithm for this somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

I would highly suggest going to your library and checking out "Algorithms 4th Edition" by Robert Sedgwick and Kevin Wayne. They have an entire chapter devoted to substring searching.
In addition, it is probably worth checking out the book website [algs4.cs.princeton.edu](http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu).

TL;DR -- If you're determined, you can whip yourself up a substring search using char arrays in guaranteed time linear to input length. There are code samples in the book and online. Doesn't get much easier than that.

Answer (score -1):

i think the "suffix tree" can solve it better with a preformance of O(log n)